# Set "nil" to subclass object in function (using inout)

Tags: ios, swift

In my view controller I've got a few views (some of them can be nil), that at some point I want to remove from superview and set view to nil. Since this operation must be performed on few views, I want to write function for that. View can be nil already, so function must be prepared for this.

*(ps. I can achieve this goal - removing views - in some other way, but I want to learn something more about Swift here)*

I've created Playground file to show the situation.

```
import UIKit

class ViewOne: UIView {

}

class ViewTwo: UIView {

}

var view1: ViewOne! = ViewOne()
var view2: ViewTwo! = ViewTwo()

func removeView(view: UIView!) {
    if view != nil {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        //error: Cannot assign to 'let' value 'view'
        view = nil
    }
}

func removeViewVar(var view: UIView!) {
    if view != nil {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        view = nil
    }
}

func removeViewInOut(inout view: UIView!) {
    if view != nil {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        view = nil
    }
}

//this method does not set view1 to nil
removeViewVar(view1)

//error: 'ViewOne' is not identical to 'UIView'
removeViewInOut(&view1)
//error: 'UIView' is not convertible to 'inout UIView!'
removeViewInOut(&view1 as UIView)

view1
```

At first I've created simple `removeView` method. Error is obvious.

Next simple modification - `removeViewVar` - but this method does not set original object to nil - after reading documentation it makes sense, I probably should use `inout` here.

But - it seems that I can't - call to `removeViewInOut` don't want to compile.

Can someone explain what exactly is not correct here? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in inout types must be exact. This is done for type-safety reasons. The solution is [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html).

```
func removeView<T: UIView>(inout view: T!) {
    if view != nil {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        view = nil
    }
}

class ViewOne: UIView {
}
var view1: ViewOne! = ViewOne()

removeView(&view1)
view1
```